# How to dynamically render views based off model in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In my program I have a front display that the user sees when they first login. They have the option to sort the various sections of this front display to their liking. Each of these boxes has a model in the database and then also a model that links to the box for that specific user and the sort order to display the boxes in.

What I need to do is go through each box in order(already figured out) and either render a view(I can work with this) or render an entire controller(probably harder) to the page.

I've had moderate success with something along these lines

In the template

```
{{#each model.character.overviewBoxesSettings }}
    {{ view App.OverviewCustomView contentBinding="this" }}
{{/each}}
```

In the view

```
App.OverviewCustomView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:function(){
        return this.get('content').get('overviewBox').get('viewName');
    }.property('content.overviewBox.viewName').cacheable(),
    _templateChanged: function() {
        this.rerender();
    }.observes('templateName')

});
```

Now this actually works, but the issue is that the views seem to persist when I change route. Also when I switch back to the front route it creates another set of the views.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html ?

Comment: That works, but I'm now having issues related to layout. Basically I'm trying to output bootstrap rows. Each of the boxes I'm outputting is 1 part of 2 of a row. As such I need a way to add customize how the collection view renders. Is this possible?

Comment: can you provide a jsbin with the last code?

Comment: So it's along these lines, http://jsbin.com/oNevoNu/1/
If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: I'll need more complete and functional code :-(